# Pass System Environment variable to properties file tomcat

Tags: tomcat

How to pass System environment variable to a tomcat properties file?

I tried the following but it isn't working:

I tried add `propertyConfigure` for `servlet xml file` like below:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
<property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
</bean>
```

Modify dep.properties file like below:

```
serverUrl=https://${DOMAIN_NAME}
serverIP=1.1.1.1
```

and start tomcat with options `CATALINA_OPTS="-DDOMAIN_NAME=example.com"` but when I try to browse the URL it ends up redirecting to `https://${DOMAIN_NAME}` without expansion.